# Histogram plot for very large data

Tags: matlab

I have  very large data of size (1 x 23750811). I would like to visualise this data in histogram-Matlab.

As the data is very large, I am getting only a single dot in my plot. But I could visualise them  separately, the first 1/4th of data and so on.

Any suggestion to visualise the entire data in a single plot at once.

Thanks !

Comment: A large data set does not imply a single dot as a histogram... post the code you are using to plot the histogram? Maybe you just need to use different bins

Comment: First of all make sure that you did not accidentally define `hist` to be a variable. (Just try `clear hist`). Probably you didn't but could lead to strange results. Then try to create a vector in a reproducible way (for example with rand?) and show it here. If all else fails, link to the file with your actual data because currently we can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Loading all your data into MatLab is inefficient; you can try using [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/); it allows you to use SQL to query very large datasets in several formats like CSV or Parquet; you can pre-compute the bins and heights, then export them and plot them using matlab.

This is a snippet you can use:

```
select
  floor(column/bin_size)*bin_size,
  count(*) as count
from "path/to/file.csv"
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Alternatively, you can try sampling your data.